# Driver problems with HP Beats Audio Laptop and Headphones Plugged In

Tags: audio, drivers, sound-card

Having some audio driver issues with my HP laptop, it comes with beats audio. None of the effects in the manufacturer's control panel work, and I can't find music listenable on my headphones without a bass booster. If I uninstall the driver and use the generic Microsoft one, the sound works great and I can enable effects in the "enhancements" tab of the sound settings.

However, within the last few weeks, sometimes when I have headphones plugged in with the Microsoft driver I get no sound. If I unplug the headphones, the sound comes out of the speakers just fine. This doesn't happen with the manufacturer's driver. Any suggestions as to what I should do, allowing me to get the audio effects I want without weird compatibility issues?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me a lot with Crap HP driver.

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/beats-audio-bugs-can-t-disable-bass-treble-messed-up-every/td-p/2808815

1. Install latest driver which is Audio IDT 6.10.6491.0 2015/09 sp63555.exe
2. Apply reg path to disable "enhancements".
3. Restore Tone Bass/treble at 0 in standard Windows audio control panel.

After many attempts, Finnaly a good audio !

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\DockHpOut\plugins\FFT]
"load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\DockHpOut\plugins\SpeakerMgr]
"load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\DockHpOut\plugins\SpeexRef]
"load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\Compressor]
"Load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\Eq]
"Load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\FFT]
"load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\HPTone]
"Load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\Limiter]
"Load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\SpeakerMgr]
"load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\SpeexRef]
"load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\GFX\LineOut\plugins\SysEq]
"Load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\LFX\DockHpOut\plugins\Placeholder]
"load"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\IDT\Apo\LFX\LineOut\plugins\SRS]
"load"=dword:00000000
```